# [Flask framework]sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError -- Error binding parameter 4 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am developing my flask blog and facing with this problem as I try to upload my image files to the site.

This is my routes.py file

```
import os
import secrets
from PIL import Image
from flask import render_template, url_for, flash, redirect, request, abort
from flaskblog import app, db, bcrypt
from flaskblog.forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm, UpdateAccountForm, PostForm
from flaskblog.models import User, Post
from flask_login import login_user, current_user, logout_user, login_required

def save_post_picture(form_picture):
    random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
    _, f_ext = os.path.splitext(form_picture.filename)
    picture_fn = random_hex + f_ext
    picture_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static/post_pics', picture_fn)

    output_size = (125, 125)
    i = Image.open(form_picture)
    i.thumbnail(output_size)
    i.save(picture_path)

    return picture_fn

@app.route("/post/new", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def new_post():
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.post_picture.data:
            picture_file = save_post_picture(form.post_picture.data)
            # post.post_image_file = url_for('static', filename='post_pics/' + post.post_image_file)
            post = Post(title=form.title.data, content=form.content.data, author=current_user,
                     post_image_file=form.post_picture.data)
            db.session.add(post)
            db.session.commit()
            post.post_image_file = url_for('static', filename='post_pics/' + post.post_image_file)
        else:
            post = Post(title=form.title.data, content=form.content.data, author=current_user)
            db.session.add(post)
            db.session.commit()
        flash('Your post has been created!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('create_post.html', title='New Post',
                           form=form, legend='New Post')
```

This is my forms.py file

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileAllowed
from flask_login import current_user
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField, TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo, ValidationError
from flaskblog.models import User

class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    content = TextAreaField('Content', validators=[DataRequired()])
    post_picture = FileField('Add post image', validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'])])
    submit = SubmitField('Post')
```

This is my models.py file

```
from datetime import datetime
from flaskblog import db, login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    post_image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}',  '{self.post_image_file}')"
```

Regarding these, how do you think I can fix the following problem when I create a new post with an image file?

Problem: [image: ew]

Note:I can save the image files to static/post_pics directory

Comment: The `post_image_file` column is defined as `String` but you give it an object. Do you want to save the file or the path to the file?

Comment: Actually, I want to save the file. I fixed the problem by changing post.post_image_file to picture_file. Obviously, form.picture.data is another type.